# Cargo build takes 30s on "metadata_register_crate"

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

While trying to debug a `tokio` build taking 1 minute, I saw this:

```
+----------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+------------+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
| Item                                   | Self time | % of total time | Time     | Item count | Incremental load time | Incremental result hashing time |
+----------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+------------+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
| run_linker                             | 34.77s    | 65.531          | 34.77s   | 1          | 0.00ns                | 0.00ns                          |
+----------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+------------+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
| metadata_register_crate                | 6.76s     | 12.749          | 30.08s   | 256        | 0.00ns                | 0.00ns                          |
+----------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+------------+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
| expand_crate                           | 1.68s     | 3.174           | 8.60s    | 1          | 0.00ns                | 0.00ns                          |
+----------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+------------+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
| LLVM_module_codegen_emit_obj           | 1.05s     | 1.987           | 1.05s    | 16         | 0.00ns                | 0.00ns                          |
+----------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+------------+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
| LLVM_passes                            | 964.32ms  | 1.817           | 964.32ms | 1          | 0.00ns                | 0.00ns                          |
+----------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+------------+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
| metadata_decode_entry_exported_symbols | 806.92ms  | 1.521           | 806.92ms | 256        | 0.00ns                | 0.00ns                          |
+----------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+------------+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
| metadata_decode_entry_impl_trait_ref   | 695.17ms  | 1.310           | 695.17ms | 885        | 0.00ns                | 0.00ns                          |
+----------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+------------+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
| incr_comp_load_dep_graph               | 673.99ms  | 1.270           | 673.99ms | 1          | 0.00ns                | 0.00ns                          |
+----------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+------------+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
| crates                                 | 552.37ms  | 1.041           | 552.37ms | 1          | 0.00ns                | 552.36ms                        |
+----------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+------------+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
Total cpu time: 53.058400104s
Filtered results account for 90.400% of total time.
+----------------------------+-----------------+
| Item                       | Artifact Size   |
+----------------------------+-----------------+
| codegen_unit_size_estimate | 101624 bytes    |
+----------------------------+-----------------+
| dep_graph                  | 9086838 bytes   |
+----------------------------+-----------------+
| linked_artifact            | 245759808 bytes |
+----------------------------+-----------------+
| object_file                | 9317344 bytes   |
+----------------------------+-----------------+
| query_cache                | 2080949 bytes   |
+----------------------------+-----------------+
| work_product_index         | 12490 bytes     |
+----------------------------+-----------------+
```

Notice this line:

```
-----+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
| metadata_register_crate                | 6.76s     | 12.749          | 30.08s   | 256        | 0.00ns                | 0.00ns                          |
+----------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+-------
```

and the 30s of time.
How can I decrease this? What does `metadata_register_crate` even mean?

I am using mold for my linker, and I am still a bit shocked by the high build times.

Also: Is there any way to interpret these rows? I don't see any relevant docs on https://github.com/rust-lang/measureme/blob/master/summarize/README.md
or measureme in general.

Comment: I'm not sure what the "Time" row means. It is pretty confusing. I think only "Self time" matters for your purposes, given that column adds up to ~48s, which is 90% of the Total cpu time.

Comment: @pitaj True, the actual build does take 1m30s or so. I think it is from the Time column.

Comment: Ah, perhaps the difference between the two is (CPU time) vs (CPU time + IO time). What kind of drive are you using?

Comment: Not sure tbh. Its running on github codespace default.

Comment: Have you tried incremental builds?

Comment: Yes. Incremental builds are on.

Answer (score 1):

This [is the code](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/fd73d01c98adb2adb570ab300ee0d5c4dc0eafca/compiler/rustc_metadata/src/creader.rs#L384) that is being timed. I've not worked with this code but it seems to be doing the recursive parsing of the crate and its dependencies, so that other code that references the crate has a struct to refer to.

It looks like you have 256 crates involved in your build (the #times column), and that 6s is spent in the function itself, 30 seconds in total when you consider the functions it calls into.

As for improving it, I'm not sure. Are builds equally slow with a hot cache? E.g. cargo build --all-targets ; cargo clean ; cargo build --all-targets ?

Comment: Seem to be faster with caching, the above example is a clean build (no cache)